Googe AMP pages are showing error in Google Page Speed Insight
We are getting couple of errors from Google AMP pages on Pagespeed Insight

Values assigned to role="" are not valid ARIA roles.

[aria-hidden="true"] elements contain focusable descendents


We have checked that these tags are auto modified form AMP in initialization and we have no control over it to modify. Example below
enter image description here
Many Google AMP pages on other website respond the same. Let us know how to resolve this issue and rank in Google pagespeed insight.
We are getting couple of errors from Google AMP pages on Pagespeed Insight

Values assigned to role="" are not valid ARIA roles.

[aria-hidden="true"] elements contain focusable descendents


We have checked that these tags are auto modified form AMP in initialization and we have no control over it to modify. Example below
